# ClassNotFoundException with Kafka Connect MQTT connector

Tags: java, apache-kafka, mqtt, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to subscribe to a mqtt topic  with kafka connect, for this I used this connector: https://github.com/johanvandevenne/kafka-connect-mqtt. I followed the steps described there with a little modification and everything seemed to work. However, when I start the connector I get a [ClassNotFoundException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHtR0.png) (screenshot) and the connector stops. It seems like it's coming from IMqttMessageListener but I don't know how to solve this.

Any ideas on what I can do?

This is my source file:

```
connector.class : be.jovacon.kafka.connect.MQTTSourceConnector
mqtt.broker : tcp://localhost:1883
mqtt.clientID: 1
mqtt.topic : test
kafka.topic: timestamp
key.converter:org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable:false
value.converter:org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter.schemas.enable:false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to copy `/target/kafka-connect-mqtt-1.0-0-package/share/kafka-connect-mqtt` to your `plugin.path` where you can be found as a configuration in [worker's configuration file](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/userguide.html#connect-configuring-workers).

Once you copy the JAR to your `plugin.path`, **make sure to restart Kafka Connect**.

---

For more details about how to install Connect plugins, refer to [Confluent's Documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/userguide.html#installing-kconnect-plugins).

Comment: Did you restart Kafka Connect?

Comment: @panador That's the problem then. How are you running Kafka Connect?

Comment: I searched for ways to restart connect but I could't find anything that does not refer to confluent. For running Kafka Connect I type connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone.properties config/connect-file-source.properties

Comment: @panador Run `ps -ef | grep connect-standalone` and find the process ID of Kafka Connect. Finally kill it by running `kill -9 processId`. And re-start it using `connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone.properties config/connect-file-source.properties`.

Comment: Tried it now, when I run ```ps -ef | grep connect-standalone``` and want to kill the process I get ```bash: kill: (8117) - No such process```. I noticed that the processId is changing whenever I run the first command.

Comment: @panador Probably you are not taking the process id. Try `ps ax | grep connect-standalone`.

Comment: The processId unfortunately keeps changing whenever I run this command, so it makes it difficult for me to kill the process. I have seen similar problems on here but no solution worked for me. It does not even work with killall...

Comment: @panador What does `pgrep connect-standalone` return?

Comment: It does not return anything

Comment: Checked and it says that Kafka Connect stopped, also checked what processes are running and the connector is not listed. When I run the connector again I get the same error though. I thought the problem is not restarting the connector but rather something with MQTT because the FileNotFoundException is caused by the IMqttMessageListener.

Comment: @panador I’m confused. So, Kafka Connect was down? Did you manage to get it started?

Comment: It seems so, I started it by running ´´´connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone.properties config/connect-file-source.properties´´´ but then I get this error again and the connector stops.

Comment: I am getting this error repeatedly and the surprising this is sink connector works. I am doing a new setup and my old setup when i received the problem I did what I have mentioned in my answer below. But this solution is not working now in my new setup.

Comment: @NiteshRatnaparkhe Have you used a different name for the new connector?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous yes, i have used a new name and different client id. But the new connector is on a new machine. Just the MQTT broker is shared between the old and new connector.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy all the 6 jars in the directory /kafka-connect-mqtt/target/kafka-connect-mqtt-1.1.0-package/kafka-connect-mqtt/. Your path is probably different from the one mentioned in the readme file for the repo that you are following.